# emacs: How to return output from command sent to comint buffer (aka inferior process)

Tags: emacs, elisp

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is

1. send a command to a running `telnet` session
2. echo the result of the command with `message`

But the general problem is sending a command to an inferior (comint) process
and waiting for output to come back and a new prompt to appear, and return the output.

I have:

```
(defun dired-vlc-test ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((buf (process-buffer dired-vlc-telnet-proc))
         (old-max (with-current-buffer buf
                    (point-max))))
    (telnet-simple-send dired-vlc-telnet-proc "get_time")
    (accept-process-output dired-vlc-telnet-proc 5)
    (message (buffer-substring-no-properties old-max (with-current-buffer buf
                                                       (point-max))))))
```

However the output I always get is "get_time", i.e. Emacs is not waiting for new output.

I got the `accept-process-output` idea from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824976/waiting-for-comint-mode-buffer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accept-process-output` returns too early in your case because it returns as soon as it has accepted some output, but in your case you want to keep accepting output until you get a new prompt.  Notice that the remote process does not tell Emacs "here's a prompt", so you will have to tweak your process filter to recognize "Oh, we received something that looks like a prompt" and you will have to call `accept-process-output` in a loop until the process filter tells it (via some global variable, probably) that it has seen a prompt.

Comment: Since I have to use process filter anyway, I just did the whole thing as one.  Thanks for the hint.